# How to install vpython with the following error?

Tags: python, vpython

I am trying to install vpython using pip install vpython. Initially, I got an error related to the trusted host issue which was answered in another question by the following command:
`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org vpython`

However, now I got another error which in essence says:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, 
setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\abkk1l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
azj_csl5\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\abkk1l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip- 
 install- 
azj_csl5\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\abkk1l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-r3b_quyt'
 cwd: C:\Users\abkk1l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azj_csl5\pywinpty\
Complete output (25 lines):
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/Cython/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate 
verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) -- Some packages may not be 
found!

Couldn't find index page for 'Cython' (maybe misspelled?)

Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) -- Some packages may not be found!

No local packages or working download links found for Cython

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\abkk1l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azj_csl5\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in 
<module>
setup(
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
_install_setup_requires(attrs)
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
return self.obtain(req, installer)
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
return installer(requirement)
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
return cmd.easy_install(req)
 File "c:\users\abkk1l\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('Cython')
```

---

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I am not sure for this but as you are getting trusted host issue can you once try running this in command while command prompt or bash is opened as administrator

Comment: Tried running as admin - getting the same error. Seeing 'Cython' mentions all over the place.

Comment: See the detailed installation information at vpython.org.